# Jam HDRPATTERN for scheme load expressions

Tags: scheme, grep, jam

I am trying to use some scheme files for code generation as a part of my jamfiles for building a project.

I have it "working" in the sense that my scheme files get evaluated as a part of the build and generate their .cpp's that get compiled and *everybody* is almost happy.

In jam I have:

Library somelib : generate.scm ;

A UserRule causes generate.scm to be executed and that outputs generate.cpp which is passed to the Object rule in jam. That bit works.

In generate.scm I have (load "included.scm") and I want jam to see that as an include by setting HDRPATTERN and HDRRULE on generate.scm, but I can't grok the egrep expression needed.

Anyone know how to write that egrep expression to match those types of statements?

Answer (score 0):

This regex worked for me (I escaped it to be Jam syntax-compliant for your convenience):

`\\(load \"(.*?)\"\\)`

I tested this using `egrep` at my command prompt. Hope it helps!